# ExoPlayer seek issue while playing .wav file

Tags: android, audio-streaming, exoplayer, seek

I am facing a problem while seeking the`.wav` file from the server. I am using ExoPlayer v2.9.6 and I can play the audio pretty well without seek. But if I try to seek the audio then it gives the error `com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 404.` And ExoPlayer state changes from READY -> BUFFERING -> to IDLE.

Does anyone know why this error/exception occurs??

OR Suggesting any other audio streaming library is also very helpful. Thank you.

Note: I am sure that the url is valid one since its being used by iOS app.